# Not able to get .then method from a subscribed service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I'm trying to get a success-error response after a patch request made inside a service. Although I can detech the success or error response in the service itself but I'm not able to "subscribe" or get a promise reply back to the function in the component who called it.

Here is the function in my component which is calling the service

```
this.os.edit({
            description: this.form.value.description,
            role_info: {
                all_learning_points: learningPointsArray
            }
        }).then((data) => {
          console.log("Data is ", data);//Can't get the value over here
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("Error is: ", error);
        });
```

Here is the function in the service

```
edit(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.model.patch(`opportunities/${this.opportunity.value.id}`, {opportunity: data})
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.opportunity.next(data); //Getting the value here
                this.router.navigate(['opportunity', this.opportunity.value.id]);
            }, error => {
                console.log("Error is: ", error);
              alert('Something went wrong');
            });
        })
    }
```

Somehow my .then is not able to capture the response thrown back by the promise in the edit function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: why are you subscribing a promsie , it should be resolved and also you need not resolve in service instead just return a promise and resolve it in component

Answer (score 1):

With Promises you need to change this line (Observer/Subject style)

```
this.opportunity.next(data);
```

into

```
resolve(data)
```

And also you have mixed to approaches together. It will be better to use only of of them